# get return vs assign for property c#

Tags: c#, properties

I'm designing a plugin system for my software. Plugins are going to be DLLs with some methods and properties. There is a "Name" string property that contains plugin name. As it is going to be totally read-only and uneditable (even for constructor) and should not change while run time, which of the following codes is better (safer)?

```cs
public string Name { get; } = "Name";
```

or

```cs
public string Name { get { return "Name"; } }
```

Comment: Both are readonly hence no much difference

Comment: The first one can be changed from the constructor, the second can't, other than that you will have to define what "better" means and it will almost certainly be subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different in that the first declares a compiler-generated field of type `string` against the type (per instance), that is initialized to `"Name"`, but you could in theory change it to be different values *in the constructor* (but not afterwards, except by reflection). The second *does not declare a field*, and will always return the same thing.

The first uses an extra tiny bit of memory per instance (although in most cases you'll never notice it due to the minimum object size). I'd use the second if the values are *always always* the same, and the first if they are *usually* the same.

As a small note: the second can be written more tersely:

```cs
public string Name => "Name";
```

Comment: So I have to use the second one as the name of a plugin is not going to change while run time. And thanks for that code!